# Make VisualStudio C# have files/folders outside of the project directory

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to come up with a setup where I can generate a visual studio solution + projectfile, that references files and folders "outside" of the folder where the .sln and .csproj's are stored.

*and* (the catch :) ), I need new files that get created with you rightclick a folder and say "new code file" to be generated in the folder that was rightclicked, which lives outside of the .sln folder.

Can it really not be done?

PS Sidenote: the reason for wanting to do this is that the .cs files are actually used by a different program, together with a lot of other files, and I don't want the .sln, .csproj, .ReSharper, .suo  etc files to clutter my directory.

Comment: Is this 'different' program written by you?
If so, then a better solution would be to leave the .cs files inside the project directory and rewrite your program to filter out the non .cs files.
A bit more information about this other program may help somebody come up with a better solution - IMHO, keeping files outside of the project directory is just creating maintenance nightmares,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to everybody for their input. It looks like what I want exactly is not possible at this point in time. Bummer.

Answer (score 8):

Add As Link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Unfortunattely, that would require the user to first make the file outside of visual studio, and then AddAsLink it. I'm hoping there is a way to wrangle things so that the user can just do Add->NewItem

Comment: this will require a VS plugin (which are fairly ugly imo)

Answer (score 3):

For anybody who is interested, it is possible to have a "linked" folder in the solution explorer instead of just the linked files appearing all on the root of the solution. Include the following in the csproj/vbproj files.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\MyFolder\*.*">
      <Link>MyFolder\A\</Link>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This will include all files from the 'MyFolder' directory one level up from the project. The 'A' can be called anything but must be there in order for the folder to appear in the solution explorer. Unfortunately using this technique you cannot add new files from the IDE as they will be added to a folder of the same name in project directory instead of to the linked directory.

Answer (score 2):

you can read my post that may help:
http://ko-sw.blogspot.com/2009/06/reusing-source-files-in-multiple-visual.html

Comment: An excerpt from that blog post:

You still choose Add Existing Item, then in the File Open dialog box you select your file and press the small arrow on the Add button. You should choose the Add As Link menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [fsutil hardlink create](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788097.aspx) ?

It wouldn't be hard to have a powershell script that slurps through your VS project directory, and creates hardlinks for each of the .cs files found, in your "other" directory.  you could have it set to run every hour, every night, on-demand, whataver.

Comment: Right.  unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem of not being able to do "Add new item" from visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

fsutil hardlink create == http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/hardlink-erstellen-SID355.aspx

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="CreateHardLinkA", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
private static extern long CreateHardLink(string lpFileName, string lpExistingFileName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

public void CreateHardLink(String sourcePath, string destPath) {
    CreateHardLink(destPath, sourcePath, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to install the Visual Assist extension, which allows adding a file relative to the directory or your currently open file.

See my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30130779/1937742) for further explanation.