# Changing the default Source File Directory in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

This is not a work-stopper in any way, but I thought I should ask anyway because it is a *little* annoying. Let's say I create a new project and start putting source files in a directory other than the default that shows up the first time. Afterwords, whenever I open the project, I have to navigate to the source directory once during that session. Like I said, not a big deal (but if solvable, then it's icing on the cake). Quite a few times I absentmindedly put the source file in the default directory and end up committing that file to the SVN and if I am lucky, going through all the files, removing them, then adding them again.

So my question is, is there any way to specify the default source directory on a per project basis?

Comment: Yeah, asked about this a while back. I haven't found any solution. I actually switched IDE for personal projects just because I found this so annoying; which is very grating, I really like VS.

Comment: Why don't you put your projects in the same directory as your "source directory"?

Comment: That is one of the solutions, yes, but I like to keep everything separate. Like I said, not a show stopper and I certainly know workarounds like the one you mentioned but in my particular set-up, it would have been nice to have that option.

Comment: The .suo file should keep the state of the project. I recall that this includes the open files and the state of the tree in the solution explorer.

Comment: The answer to this question might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321404/vc2010-c-organizing-source-files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make VisualStudio C# have files/folders outside of the project directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717613/make-visualstudio-c-sharp-have-files-folders-outside-of-the-project-directory)

Answer (score 3):

I have run into the same nuisance. I like to put the public interface header files for a library in a separate directory, but end up with file directory typos because I forget to navigate to the correct directory when saving a new file. Unfortunately, Visual Studio does not offer a setting to change the default directory for new C++ source files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I started using build systems (CMake, Premake) which requires me to keep my project files separate from my source files, which hampered my workflow.

Although changing the default source directory seems impossible, if you aren't afraid to spend money, the workaround I found was to use the [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) extension.

- You can bind a shortcut of your choise to the [Create File](http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W288) command which creates
  a new file relative to the directory or your open file.
- I'd also recommend to base one's workflow around the wonderful
  [Create from Usage](http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W164) command (which I think greatly boosts
  productivity) which almost eliminates the need to manually create files.

The extension is great, albeit a bit costly. I would love to see Microsoft incorporate these features directly in the IDE eventually as they are found vanilla in a lot of other IDEs e.g. Eclipse, Intellij.

There might be some free extensions available that does the same thing, but I haven't found any.

Answer (score -2):

Changing the Default Project Folder may help. [This page](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VS2005ProjectFolder.aspx) demonstrates how to change the default for Visual Studio 2005, and it should be the same for later versions.

Comment: The problem is not the default folder for all projects, but the default source directory for each individual project. Visual studio should write that information in each project file to know where its source files are put so that any time I want to create a new source file for a particular project, it always goes to the directory I selected, and not the default which is usually the folder the project is in.