# Is it possible to organize c++ header and cpp files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm not sure if i'm asking a valid question, but here goes.

I have c++ solution with a structure of

[folder] Header files -

... 200 header files ..

[folder] Source files -

... 200 soure files ..

... rest

Is it possible to organize header and soure files by folders as you would in a C# project? The problem I'm facing is, as the project grows, it gets tiresome to navigate through a huge pile of files, which would be much easier to navigate to, if they were organized by functionality (such as folders and namespaces in c# projects).

Is there a some kind of standard, that would be supported by a wide variety of compilers and not Visual Studio alone ?

Example:

[folder] Header files -

- [folder] X domain

  - 100 header files
- [folder] Y domain

  - 100 header files

[folder] Source files -

- [folder] X domain

  - 100 cpp files
- [folder] Y domain

  - 100 cpp files

... rest

Comment: Most compilers do not care where your source and header files are located.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Header/Source file is not a requirement imposed by Visual Studio. That's just the default layout, and it's virtual, not physical. If you click "Show all files" in the solution explorer, it will show the folder tree as it is on the hard drive- which you can manipulate as you see fit. This is the only sane configuration and I have no idea why the default is that way. Plus, naturally, they fixed it for C# projects but not C++.

Comment: DeadMG, never before have I felt more indebted to you. The project layout was my major gripe with VS - I've searched before but all posts I found said it wasn't possible. Can't believe I didn't try this myself...

Comment: I didn't find it either, and when I asked, I was also told it was impossible. It boggles the mind that it's not the default, nor more widely-known- nor indeed easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a standard but you can put headers (and source) files in any folder structure you like.

You need to ensure that either the include files are referenced by relative path or add the folder to the projects search path.