# Visual Studio 2012 filters?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just decided to learn C++ and I installed Visual Studio 2012. My friend told me it's a monstrous program and I should avoid it, but it has one of the best compiler ever (advanced error messages, etc.) and i found it useful in studying.

The problem is there are option called Filter except for real Folders. Source code is organized in IDE but the project folder is just messy, everything is in the root.

I think it's good for the compiler - you can't be wrong while including files. But since u want to share your source files with your friends who don't use VS it's necessary to have files organized in folders.

Is there any option to export files into folders based on filers?

Comment: can't you just put your source files into folders however you want, then organize your filters to match your actual folders?

Comment: Do what @mark said, and refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12360211/241631)

Comment: OK, I'm probably blind, but... where is the "Show all files" option please? I don't see it anywhere in the solution explorer panel.

Comment: @Jiri It's one of the little buttons at the top of the Solution Explorer pane, above the tree view that shows the files. (I don't have VS installed on this machine to give you a more helpful answer)

Comment: WoW, finally, I got it, thank you guys :)