# Header File Not Recognized

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been working on a problem for class for over 6 hours, and have hit a confusing roadblock. Not sure what mistake I have made, and I've tried moving things, removing includes, adding includes, and even removing the following class.

The problem I've had so far is that the functions I made prototypes for in the header and then defined in the source file are not being recognized by the `source.cpp` in use.

This is all written in Visual Studio 2015 C++

File names are: `monty.h` and `monty.cpp` in order.

We are given two sample `source.cpp` files in order to test our work, however neither is giving me any results due to this error.

The main function provided states `#include "monty.h"` however the issue persists.

Header:

```
#ifndef MONTY_H
#define MONTY_H

class Monty{
private:
    int wins; // Number of Wins
    int ran; // Random Number Variable
    int val; // Value to determine win/loss via functions
    int x; // Determines number of times to repeat a function
    int count; // Counts number of times function repeated

    static int k(int); // 'Keep' choice function
    static int s(int); // 'Switch' choice function
    static int r(int); // 'Random' choice function

public:
    bool monty(char);
    int monty(char, int);
};
#endif
```

Source File:

```
#include "monty.h" // Including header file & other necessary libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool Monty::monty(char y){
    x = 1; // Setting count variable to 1 in order to prevent functions from repeating.
    if (y == 'k') // Calling functions depending on char input
        val = k(x);
    if (y == 's')
        val = s(x);
    if (y == 'r')
        val = r(x);

    if (val == 1) // Determining win/loss and returning value.
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int Monty::monty(char y, int z){
    x = z; // Initializing independent count variable
    wins = 0; // Initializing dependent wins variable
    count = 0;
    while (count < x) {
        if(monty(y))
            wins++;
    }
    return wins; // Returning number of wins
}

int Monty::k(int x) {
    int ran;
    ran = rand() % 3; // Obtaining a random number from 0 to 2
        if (ran == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
}

int Monty::s(int x){
    int ran;
    ran = rand() % 3; // Obtaining a random number from 0 to 2
        if (ran == 1 || ran == 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
}

int Monty::r(int x) {
    int ran;
    ran = rand() % 2; // Obtaining random number from 0 to 1
        if (ran == 0)
            return k(x);
        else
            return s(x);
}
```

The two main functions we are given are written by the instructor, and as far as I can tell, are without error, as I seem to be the only student having this issue. It's likely I made a rookie mistake, but I doubt I'm the first.

Edits:

Exact Code for the error:

`C3861 : 'monty': identifier not found - File: source.cpp - Line 18`

Requested sample main file

```
// monty_test1.cpp - Test program #1 for Monty module

#include "monty.h"

#include <climits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static char get_strategy ();

int main () {

    // Initialize random number generator
    srand(time(0));

    cout << "Testing monty function..." << endl << endl;

    // Call monty function with user's choice of strategy, and report result
    if (monty(get_strategy()))
        cout << "Contestant won." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Contestant lost." << endl;

#ifdef _WIN32
    system("pause");
#endif

    return 0;
}

// Prompt for and input strategy, with validation
static char get_strategy () {

    // Get strategy, must be 's', 'k', or 'r'.
    char strategy;
    cout << "Enter strategy (s, k, r): ";
    cin >> strategy;

    // Validate input
    while (strategy != 's' && strategy != 'k' && strategy != 'r') {
        cout << "Stragegy is not valid. Try again." << endl;
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cin >> strategy;
    }

    // Discard any remaining input
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

    return strategy;
}
```

Solution found was removing the class referring to the `monty` functions as the main function could not be edited.

[Requested Information about File Organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSd3x.png)

Comment: Please post the error messages you are seeing.

Comment: What's the error message ? The error message probably says what is going wrong.

Comment: "and then defined in the resource file": what does this mean ??? Presumably "and included in the source file"...

Comment: how have you organized your files in the source directory? If you're uncertain how to view the source files how they're organized on the hard drive, [click show all files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12360211/4892076) in the solution explorer window.

Comment: You have two `=` instead of `==` errors, that I've fixed in the review, and you mistakenly call "source" files, i.e. `.cpp` files, "resource" files, which I've fixed as well. In CS, every word counts! It's a *very* precise field.

Comment: I'd suggest you post the main.cpp, referred to as the "source file", and the exact compiler errors here. Again, this is a very precise science! "Some errors" simply doesn't cut it.

Comment: Post the source file containing main.cpp as well!

Comment: What .cpp file and line number does `C3861` reference?

Comment: `if (monty(get_strategy()))` There is no global function `monty` in the code you posted, and `Monty::monty` is a non-static member function. You probably want to instantiate a `Monty` object, then call its `monty` member function.

Comment: The error references the `source.cpp` file, line 18. I'll add it in a moment.

Comment: @dxiv I'll be honest, I have no idea what you're trying to tell me to do.

Comment: Something like `bool monty(char y) { Monty hall; return hall.monty(y); }`.

Comment: Jared Taylor, see my edited answer for the complete solution together with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A short answer, suggested by dxiv:**

Provided that we can't change the last two files at all, we can declare a global function `monty(char)` and have it create a temporary object of class `Monty`, and then call its `monty(char)` function like this:

Add to monty.h:

```
bool monty(char c);
```

Add to monty.cpp:

```
bool monty(char c)
{
    return Monty.monty(c);
}
```

But that would anyway be a cludge, and not how classes are meant to be used.

**A long answer:**

```
// Call monty function with user's choice of strategy, and report result
if (monty(get_strategy())) { /*...*/ }
```

What exactly is `monty`? You obviously mean to call `Monty::monty(char)`, but you forget to create an object of the class `Monty` first!

Should go like this:

```
int main () {
        // Initialize random number generator
    srand(time(0));    
    cout << "Testing monty function..." << endl << endl;

    Monty myMonty;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // Call monty function with user's choice of strategy, and report result
    if (myMonty.monty(get_strategy()))
        cout << "Contestant won." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Contestant lost." << endl;

#ifdef _WIN32
    system("pause");
#endif
        return 0;
}
```

To be more precise:

As noted above, you intend to call a non-static member function of the class `Monty`. Hence, you need to first create an object of such a class, and then call the function on that object. The compiler error you see occurs since you have not declared the `monty` variable anywhere before using it, hence `cannot find identifier` (identifier == the name of the variable in this context).

*Edit per the OP's comment:*

In C++, there really, really is no way to call a class' function, be it static or not, without mentioning the class' name or the class object's name. Thus, the expression `monty(get_strategy())` implies that `monty` is either tha name of a global or local function, which is not what you've designed, obviously; or it is the name of an object with the overloaded `operator(...)`, in which case we call it a functor object. Neither is the case with the code you've posted, so to make it work with the immutable professor's code, you want to redesign it a bit and make `monty(char)` a global function, instead of a public member function.

Comment: Ouch, my bad! Thank you a lot.

Comment: The `source.cpp` file is not of my design. Any changes I make there would be unfortunately useless as my professor will likely use the provided code above to test the files I created, which would be the former two. I'm looking for a solution that does not include changing the `source.cpp` file. Thank you for trying to help though.

Comment: Sorry, but the way C++ works, that's the only way to call a non-static function of a class!

Comment: @JaredTaylor Then create a global function that instantiates a `Monty` object and calls its `Monty::monty` member function.

Comment: Removed the class itself, and it seems to be working just fine now. Thanks for the help from both of you. I'd prefer to use a class, but I suppose it just won't work out here. Very frustrating sometimes. For a first time using this site it's been very helpful. You two have a good night/morning/evening/afternoon wherever you are.

Comment: Good to know we've helped you. Be sure to accept the answer as well!